# ModuleNotFoundError - Python and Python3 returns different path

Tags: python, macos, python-poetry

Poetry shows a ModuleNotFoundError, although I did install Django.

`poetry init` -> `poetry add Django` -> `poetry install` -> `poetry shell` -> `poetry install` again to have it covered both ways.

My virtual env for poetry - `poetry env info` :

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.10.5
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/Desktop/PythonProjects/0_testDrivenTutorial/.venv
Valid:          True

System
Platform: darwin
OS:       posix
Python:   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10
```

The .venv is in the project folder and contains Django, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I am running within the .venv, but I still get ModuleNotFoundError, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

**Update:**

Both below commands are executed within `poetry shell`
When I do which python, I get:

```
python: aliased to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
```

When I do which python3, I get:

```
/Users/name/Desktop/PythonProjects/0_testDrivenTutorial/.venv/bin/python3
```

I have to execute python3, and then it sees the Django.
So, I seem to have two separate pythons within the poetry shell.

Is this correct behavior that the `python` command within `poetry shell` does not point to the `python3` in the `.venv` but rather to the system's python?

Comment: You most likely accidentally created 2 separate virtual environments

Comment: @mousetail that is correct, python seems to not point to the virtual environment created but to the alias in the system. Is this correct behavior that python does not point to the python3 in the venv and to the system one?

Comment: The results of `which` suggest either the venv is half activated or half created. I'd delete the entire virtual env then let poetry create a new one.

Comment: I did create a new project from scratch, deleted .venv, re-done all the steps, and still the poetry python points to the system's python same issue.